# Looking for Light Time Management Software Suggestions (for Mac)

Tags: mac, project-management

I'm looking for a simple project management app that performs task scheduling, along the line of Merlin or MS Project, but no where near as robustly. I don't need to deal with other (human) resources, but I work on anything from 3 to 6 different projects at a time. What I'd like is to be able to input deadlines and tasks, and have a schedule suggested to complete them.

I do technical work, but I don't think I need anything specifically for software development, especially considering I do plenty of other kinds of things, like graphic design and social media PR.

I'd really like this to be dead simple, as simple as possible. Suggestions? OmniPlan, something web-based? Definitely cannot afford anything too extravagant, really looking for something under $200.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for options, I found the [Lifehacker "Hive Five" for time management applications](http://lifehacker.com/5362829/five-best-time+tracking-applications) and it looks like there are some good options presented there that will work on a Mac or are OS independent. The overall winner of the voting is actually "Other", so time tracking is very different for different people and looking through the comments on that page should give you some other ideas and options as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [FogBugz](http://www.fogbugz.com/) for [students and startups](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/StudentAndStartup.html)?  It may not suggest a schedule, but it does have evidence based scheduling.  It is also a great resource for managing the tasks themselves (sending emails, organizing data, organizing bug reporting, wiki for documentation, etc).  Student and startup edition is free for up to two users, so it wouldn't hurt to check it out.

Comment: I like the idea of evidence-based scheduling, and god knows I'm the worst at estimates. This might be worth trying, even though I have several other task management tools. My only problem here is that I rarely perform the same types of tasks twice.

Comment: EBS is more for estimating based on your estimation skills.  If you are consistently over-estimating the time, then it will schedule based on that.  For me, however, FogBugz is the best task management tool I've ever used.  Much better than freeware bug tracking software.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RationalPlan Multi Project](http://www.rationalplan.com) if you need to manage multiple projects at once. It is easy to use and has an affordable price.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try **Doolphy**, our online **project management tool**. It is an easy to use application that allows you to plan your projects and tasks. Doolphy has Gantt Charts and time reports that help you to organize your time individually too, so you can meet all the deadlines.

We have different price plans according to the number of projects and storage size available, but you can also create a free account as well. You can find us at https://www.doolphy.com